# How can i convert three Doctrine queries to single one in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing this in my controller

```
$C100 = $em->getRepository('AcmeJunkieBundle:Junk')->findBy(array('type'=> 'C100'),array('day' => 'ASC'));
$C200 = $em->getRepository('AcmeJunkieBundle:Junk')->findBy(array('type'=> 'C200'),array('day' => 'ASC'));
$C300 = $em->getRepository('AcmeJunkieBundle:Junk')->findBy(array('type'=> 'C300'),array('day' => 'ASC'));
```

'type' is just string field

IS there any way to do that in single query and then do something like

```
$C100 = $result['C100']
$C200 = $result['C200']
$C300 = $result['C200']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to know about your `Junk` entity: is `type` just a string field?

Anyway you may write your own repository methods in associated repository class: your `Junk` class source will be something like this I assume:

**src/Acme/JunkieBundle/Entity/Junk.php**

```
namespace Acme\JunkieBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\JunkieBundle\Repository\JunkRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="junk")
 */

class Junkie{ ... }
```

Make sure you have an annotation with the repository class name, then write up that class - the one being fetched by `$C100 = $em->getRepository()` method in the controller.

**src/Acme/JunkieBundle/Repository/JunkRepository.php**

```
namespace Acme\JunkieBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class JunkRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findByTypes(array $types)
    {

        //we build our query here           
        $qb = $this -> createQueryBuilder();

        $query = $qb -> where( $qb -> expr() -> in ('type', $types) )
        -> getQuery();

        return $query -> getResults();

    }


}
```

Now you may call

```
$em->getRepository('AcmeJunkieBundle:Junk')->findByTypes(array('C100', 'C200', 'C300'))
```

in your controller.

Be sure to check [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/index.html) docs.

Answer (score 1):

you can do just :

```
$em->getRepository('AcmeJunkieBundle:Junk')
   ->findBy(array('type'=> array('C100', 'C200', 'C300')),array('day' => 'ASC'));
```

;) thanks